# how can i refresh div with clicked anchor href attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, refresh

I have 2 or 3 links that related to another page of my website and I have a div tag.
I want that, when I click on one of my links , the page content that its address is given to href attribute ,start to showing in my div without refresh all the page.

Comment: Any code of yours we can see?

Comment: @Majid stackoverflow is not a "do the code for me" service.

Comment: The most simple solution to this would be an iFrame, where you change the src attribute to the href attribute of the link tag.

Comment: No, I want to do this with jquery and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about AJAX. Just make AJAX request on click of those links and load the content in the div tag.

So your event will need following functions-

`jQuery().click()`, `jQuery.ajaxStart()`,`jQuery.get()` or `jQuery.load()` based on your needs...

Comment: Ok ... Would you please generate the code with ajax?

Comment: Dude... You try, we will back you up... Give a try and show your effort.